# Java Hashmap and 2D array performance with the known index

Tags: java, arrays, hashmap

I have used Hashmap and 2D array to read an excel.

Hashmap - All the data will be converted to string and  saved with a unique string key  rowno+colno
    example : key 11 - Data of  Row1 ,column1

2D array - All the data will be converted to string and get stored.
    arr[00] ="Data of  Row1 ,column1"

Once it get stored. I need to use those data in multiple times where i know the index.

say ex..If I want to get the data of 1st row 3rd column I will use the below.

HAsmap - String value = Hm.get("13")

2Darray - String value =  arr[02]

In this case which one is faster. I need to store a huge level of data.

Comment: A 2D array should be marginally faster. But most importantly, your first technique won't work. What is key 123, is it row 1, column 23, or row 12, column 3? You should design a Key class, with two integers, and a correct equals() and hashCode() methods, rather than using a String.

Comment: Also a 2D array is accessed by arr[0][2]. A notation such as arr[02] is meaningless for a bidimensional array, unless you need the first row, in which case you can use arr[0].

Comment: @JBNizet Thank you. you are right first technique won't work.I need to use 2D array.

Answer (score 3):

A bi dimensional array is faster to access data, but you need also to consider the space occupancy.

If you need to store **all the cells** a bi dimensional array is faster too, but if you need only to store few cells you have to use what is named a sparsed matrix, in this case a Map is the best solution in terms of space used, and the performances are similar, so use less memory is better (less GC).

Basically it is possible to have the following matrix

```
                     bi dimensional array  |     Map      
                     Space     | Speed     |     Space    | Speed
                     -------------------------------------------
                               |           |              |
Store all data       Best      | Best      |     Good     |  Good
Store few            Very bad  | Very good*|  Very good   |  Good
```

*) Consider that the overall speed of you application can be strongly slowed if GC happens frequently and using a very big bi dimensional matrix where few records are used can do that.

Comment: Thank you..I will go for Array